# Cannot set property innerHTML of null on appended child (div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, appendchild

Before I learn some Unity I wanted to be able to create a simple Javascript game out of my own knowledge. So, I started experimenting with a timer and it worked. Then I wanted to add a div element to my HTML document and have its text change in response to the timer. So I wrote this code:

```js
var counter = 0;
var seconds = 0;

$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var element = document.createElement("div");
  element.id = "text2";
  document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(element);

  function gameActions() {
    document.getElementById("canvas").innerHTML = seconds;
    if (seconds == 1) document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = "second";
    else document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = "seconds";

    counter++;

    if (counter % 50 == 0) {
      seconds++;
    }

  }

  setInterval(gameActions, 20);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas" class="imgcenter" style="width: 500px; height: 400px; background-color: #eeffee;">

</div>
```

Basically I'm intending to change the text of the "parent" div which displays the number of seconds passed after the html page is fully loaded. But before that, I'm trying to create a `div` with id `text2` to add it inside the div parent.This div should display the word "seconds" depending on the time (basically display "second" when the seconds variable is 1, and "seconds" when not)

Where "imgcenter" is only CSS to specify auto margin. The error is that, whenever I run this on Chrome, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

Am I correct to assume the div is not being added? Am I missing a step in the addition? Please let me know what you think the error is, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.id = "text2";
document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(element);
```

… puts the element you are trying to target inside the canvas div.

This code:

```
    document.getElementById("canvas").innerHTML = seconds;
```

… **destroys everything in that element** and replaces it with the HTML in the `seconds` variable.

> Am I correct to assume the div is not being added?

No. The div is added, but then you destroy it before trying to do anything with it.

Comment: Wow, really? That's crazy! Is there a way to have text along with my div? Should I try to append the text before the div?

Comment: It's probably easiest to put an element in there to hold the seconds at the same time as you create text2, then update the innerHTML of that.

Comment: Well, then I guess if I have a container div I shouldn't mess with it directly, other than creating elements within it. I keep forgetting innerHTML is not setText!

Answer (score 0):

In your line `document.getElementById("canvas").innerHTML = seconds;` you are replacing your complete innterHTML of `canvas`. By that your element `text2` is removed again.

If you want to show the unit independently from the seconds in it's own element, you should create an element `unit`for example like this:

```js
var counter = 0;
var seconds = 0;

$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    var unit = document.createElement("div"); // create a second element unit
    element.id = "text2";
    unit.id = "unit"; // asign the id unit
    document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(element);
    document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(unit);

    function gameActions() {
        document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML = seconds; // replace the unit with the valuen of seconds
        if (seconds == 1) document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = "second";
        else document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = "seconds";

        counter++;

        if(counter % 50 == 0) {
            seconds++;
        }

    }

    setInterval(gameActions, 20);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas" class="imgcenter" style="width: 500px; height: 400px; background-color: #eeffee;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the element you added when you replace the inner HTML of the canvas.  It would be better if you just updated the entire contents with the entire string instead of creating a separate element.  I would also wrap it in an IIFE so that the variables don't leak into the global scope.

```
(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    var seconds = 0;

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    function gameActions() {
        canvas.innerHTML = seconds + " second" + (seconds > 1 ? "s" : "");

        counter++;

        if (counter % 50 == 0) {
            seconds++;
        }

    }

    $(function() {
        setInterval(gameActions, 20);
    });
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1unn153b/